# Form distorts when zooming

Tags: html, css

I  have a form with two input elements and a textarea. When I zoom in/out the sizes of the objects change. Is there a way to stop this behaviour? At 100% zoom it looks ok, but if someone uses their browser with 90% zoom or 110% it looks distorted.

```
<table class="upload" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
                <p><b>Name:</b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" name="appname" size="50" maxlength="32">
        </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><b>Age:</b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
                <textarea  name="adtext" cols="39" rows="2" maxlength="75" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><b>Website:</b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="marketlink" size="50" maxlength="254">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="drawAd()">Test link</button>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.upload {
 border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;

}
table.upload td {
border:0px solid black;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
table.upload td input{
outline: #388c91;
margin-left:4px;
}

table.upload td textarea{
margin-left:4px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop styling elements width using `size`/`cols` attributes and use CSS instead:

```
table.upload td input, table.upload td textarea {
    width: 250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vrd2q/

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the input sizes are being calculated with `em` which is relative to the `font-size` (that changes with different zoom levels). Try specifying the width in a absolute unit, such as `px`.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping people being able to zoom in or out is a usability booboo. Don't use the tag attributes 'size' and 'cols' (remove those attributes, as @MarcinJuraszek mentioned), but use CSS to either give an equal absolute (px) or relative (em) width to the input and textarea fields. I.e.

```
input,
textarea {
    width: 15em;
}
```

In the case of em (which is arguably prefered), the width of the fields will scale according to the zoom factor, but at least they will all scale the same.